# A tricky diophantine equation with factorials

Tags: number-theory, inequality, diophantine-equations, problem-solving, factorial

I am being unable to solve this diophantine equation. Does anyone have any suggestions. Let $n$ and $m$ both be non-negative integers. Find all solutions to

$$n(nm - 2)! = (n!)^m$$

How would one solve this? I suspect there is a bounding argument. Is there a classical number theory argument? What about a combinatorial argument?

Comment: where did you get it?

Comment: I created it myself. I seeing if I could find ways to solve cubic and quartics by myself without help from google. My method will apply to certain solutions of the above equation.

Comment: unless $n$ is very small, $m$ must be $1,$ as there will be primes larger than $n$ but no larger than $nm-2.$

Comment: What about $(n,m) = (2,2)$ and $(2,1)$?

Comment: "Bertrand's postulate, is a theorem stating that for any integer n > 3, there always exists at least one prime number p with

    n < p < 2n - 2.

A weaker but more elegant formulation is: for every n > 1 there is always at least one prime p such that

    n < p < 2n. "    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: There is a theorem that says that there is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$ (and actually, the constant $2$ can be reduced if a lower bound on $n$ is used). So if $m > 2$, you should be able to find a prime strictly in between $n$ and $nm - 2$, at least if $n > 3$, and then your equation can't hold. Also, using the lowered constant, (for $n$ large enough), you will also be able to rule out $m=2$ when $n$ is above the needed lower bound for the lowered constant.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a prime greater than $n$ and at most $nm-2$, it divides the left side but not the right side.  Bertrand's hypothesis almost gives this to you.